# Looking for Pictures Joining/Merging Software

Tags: images, image-processing, merge

Iam looking for simple software that will combine multiple pictures into one. At this point iam not even interested in blending options (which i might like anyway). I just want them next to each other in 2x2 or 6x2 or any other way that i would wish. The most important thing is. I want to be able to freely move positon of images as a preview. (just to be able to see what looks the best).
I tried really a lot of programs. None of them worked the way i wanted. In some it would take hours to achieve results..
I found this site: http://www.photojoiner.net 
Which at first look does exacly what i want. But...
 1. it's online.
 2. It does't resize images (just add white background to fit) 
3. Changing order is bothersome since it moves whole rows.
But yes i want software as simple as this. If it gives me options to blend them, or give nice borders. Alright but most important. That it's easy fast and allow previews, and order change.

I made image showing what i want as final result. (amount of images will vary)
[image]

Till now i was able to get this kind of result by using irfanview. It has option to create panorama image. Which simply puts specified images next to each other in horizontal or vertical way, automatically resizing to fit well. Unfortunately it is taking a lot of time. It does not have a preview and selecting goes by file names. And i would like see how final result looks with different order of pictures.

Would be grateful to finally find something like this.

Comment: Try hugin it is a free stitching product